# Atualizando do IONIC 1 para o 3: Como fazer login em JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2, ionic3

Estou migrando de Ionic 1 para o 3, e quantas mudanças.

Criei minha API de login, com token:

[image: Aqui coloco meu código de autorização para acesso a API]

Aqui coloco meu código de autorização para acesso a API.

E aqui o resultado em JSON:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ion-content padding id="page8" style="background-color:#050505;">
    <img src="assets/img/XJWNOP1BQ3WQ94lyrnTe_logo.gif" style="display:block;width:60%;height:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" />
    <form>
        <!--    <div style="width:100%;height:220px;margin:0px 0px;line-height:250px;background-color:#e8ebef;text-align:center;">
            <i class="icon ion-image" style="font-size:64px;color:#888;vertical-align:middle;"></i>
        </div> -->
        <div class="spacer" style="width:300px;height:37px;"></div>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>
                    Email
                </ion-label>
                <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="usuario.email" name="email" placeholder=""></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>
                    Senha
                </ion-label>
                <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.senha" name="senha" placeholder=""></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <div class="spacer" style="height:40px;"></div>
        <button (click)="submit()" ion-button color="stable" block>
      Entrar
    </button>
        <button ion-button color="positive" block icon-left (click)="loginWithFB()">
      <ion-icon name="facebook"></ion-icon>
      Entrar pelo Facebook
    </button>
        <button ion-button clear color="positive" block on-click="goToCriarConta()">
      Crie sua conta
    </button>

        <button ion-button clear color="positive" block>
      Esqueci a Senha
    </button>

    </form>
```

Até aqui, tudo bem...

Mas agora vem a atualização: Como posso passar esses parametros para a minha API e fazer o login? Estou fazendo desta forma, mas não funciona, está errada:

```
submit(){
    var link = 'http://localhost/rest/usuario/read_one.php';
    var data = '?email='+ JSON.stringify(this.usuario.email)  + '&senha='+ JSON.stringify(this.usuario.senha);


    this.http.get(link)
      .subscribe(data => {
       this.data.response = data._body;

       if(this.data.response != "[]"){
        var resposta = this.data.response;
        console.log(resposta);

        // tinha que pegar o ID do usuário.... :/
         sessionStorage.setItem("usuarioEmail", this.usuario.email);
         //sessionStorage.setItem("idUsusario", resposta[0].idusuarios);
         sessionStorage.setItem("flagLogado", "sim");

         this.navCtrl.setRoot(WellFitPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: "forward"});
        }else{
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Usuário Não encontrado!',
            subTitle: 'Verifique se digitou seu e-mail e senha corretamente.',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
       }
    })
  }
```

Como posso fazer de forma correta? Não estou conseguindo. Preciso de ajuda. Já li tudo quanto é tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramos, sua API espera receber uma requisição POST e você está enviando um GET.

```
   this.http.get(link)
```

Para enviar o dado da maneira correta utilize

```
var data = JSON.stringify(this.usuario);
this.http.post(link , data)
.subscribe(response => { *Continue...* });
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas Brogni, deu certo a sua referencia. :)

Comment: Por nada @Ramos !